# Ecto where like query acts like where ==

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to get an ecto like query working like this:

```
def find(searchterm) do
  query = from c in Contact, 
  #where: fragment("? % ?", c.company_name, ^searchterm),
  where: like(c.company_name, ^searchterm),
  contacts = Repo.all(query)
  {:ok, contacts}
end
```

In my table, I have a company_name "Asymptote".  Using where: like/2 my query looks like this:

```
SELECT c0."id", c0."company_id", c0."company_name" FROM "contacts" AS c0 WHERE (c0."company_name" LIKE $1) ["Asym"] (1.0ms)
```

when the pg_trm search uncommented, it looks like this:

```
SELECT c0."id", c0."company_id", c0."company_name" FROM "contacts" AS c0 WHERE (c0."company_name" % $1) ["Asym"] (1.0ms)
```

As far as I can see, the queries look good, but there are no results.  Since I added the index after adding "Asymptote" to the database, I expect that is why it isn't found in the pg_trm index, but why won't like/2 or ilike/2 work? When entering in the full name "Asymptote", I am able to find the record.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the default similarity match limit with pg_trgm.  It is able to find shorter values in my company_name column just fine (like "google"), so I think this is a problem with the default limit parameter.  like/2 shouldn't work that way though

Answer (score 11):

I faced some similar problem. Unfortunately I had no pg_trgm available. I used the LIKE as in:

```
  from candidate in query,
  where: like(candidate.first_name, ^("%#{text}%"))
```

This matched the text in any place of the candidate.first_name.

Comment: Why does the `^` have to be before the entire statement?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mitchell Henke of Rokkincat, here's a way to get pg_trgm working with custom match percentages:

```
def find(searchterm) do
  limit = 0.1
  query = from c in Contact, 
  where: fragment("similarity(?, ?) > ?", c.company_name, ^searchterm, ^limit),
  #where: like(c.company_name, ^searchterm),
  contacts = Repo.all(query)
  {:ok, contacts}
end
```

But I still can't get like/2 working.  Also, I don't see where in Ecto source this function exists.